# How to publish to Microsoft Store from Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I'm creating an application with MAUI and .NET 8. After some issues, I finally managed to create a package to deploy on the Microsoft Store.

Now, I want to deploy the application automatically from Visual Studio to the Microsoft Store. I read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps). This documentation does not reflect what the current settings are in Visual Studio or in the Microsoft Store itself.

When I arrive at this screen

[image]

When I click on `Automatically submit...`, I get this screen

[image]

Now, from the Microsoft Store and based on the documentation, "On the Partner Center dashboard, select the gear icon (near the upper right corner of the dashboard) and then select Developer settings." but there are no options for it. I create a new Entra ID.

[image]

Then I created an application in the `App Registration` section of the `Entra ID`.

[image]

Then, in the `Certificates and secrets`, I created a new `Client Secret` for the app. I copied the `Tenant ID` and the `Client ID` and the `Client Secret` and pasted in the Visual Studio window.

[image]

Now, I can click on `Launch Windows App Certification Kit`. The app passed all tests! The submission failed because there was an authentication problem.

[image]

Do you know what I can do? What is the right way to create the credentials?

Comment: Does the user have an account on the machine?  Could issue be a domain issue?  The error indicates the user credentials cannot be verified.  It may take time before a new user account is recognized over a corporate network that have many Password Servers.  The credentials are slowly passed from server to server.  Check if the user can login to the machine.

Comment: Let me make sure what you're asking. The question reads _How to publish to Microsoft Store from Visual Studio 2022_ which is pretty straightforward and something I'd attempt to answer. In the text of your post you state _I  want to deploy the application **automatically**_ and it becomes about the credentials and API authorization. Dragging the **.msix** bundle onto the drag-drop interface of the Microsoft Partner Center is a super-easy way to publish, but (correct me if I'm wrong) that doesn't sound like what you're looking for here...

Comment: @IV. yes, I can create the package on my local machine and then drag & drop it on the website. Because Visual Studio 2022 offers the option to deploy automatically to the Microsoft Store, I don't know what credentials Visual Studio is looking for. If you read the documentation, they say to go in the Microsoft Store and create a user from there but this documentation is definitely not in line with the current version of VS and the store.

Comment: Did you associate Azure Active Directory with your Partner Center account? You can [follow this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#associate-azure-active-directory-with-your-partner-center-account) to publish it to the Microsoft store.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT yes, I have associated the AAD to the Partner Center. The document you sent is not updated. There is no option named _Developer settings_ in the Partner Center.